# Can Not Process URL If Special Character Is In Path Using Chilkat Library

Tags: c#, chilkat

i am trying to get data from a link using chilkat http library using following method/function:

```
sHTML = oHTTP.QuickGetStr(URL);
```

it's works find with all type of url except if the url has special char in it's path

example:

**Note: it has ; (semicolon) after the base url and before the parameters**

```
https://securedomain.com/3.0/api/sports/league/matches/MatchId/topplayerstats.json;type=fantasy_points;type=tackles;type=runs;type=run_metres;type=post_contact_metres?limit=3&userkey=APIKey
```

chilkat response "404" error for this kind of url

i have also tried to replace the semicolon (;) with %3B but that didn't work either

if i try the same link on browser or even try with curl it just works fine :)

any one knows how handle that kind of url with chilkat?

best regards

Comment: @quaabaam, thanks a lot for your reply.. did try.. but didn't work sir.. :( it throws 400 (bad request).

Comment: My other comment is incorrect, I deleted it. I gave you wrong advice in error. The correct advice, the URL uses a `?` to separate resource path from [URL Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#parameters). And `&` is used to separate the parameter 'key=value' pairs. The `;` may also be used here too. So, you may want to try this for your URL; https://securedomain.com/3.0/api/sports/league/matches/MatchId/topplayerstats.json?type=fantasy_points;type=tackles;type=runs;type=run_metres;type=post_contact_metres;limit=3&userkey=APIKey

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried \x or /x (x being the special char?)